# Use of - and * in clojure function names

Tags: clojure

Every so often I run into a bit of clojure code where a function name either begins with "-" or ends with "*" and while I can make some guesses from the context, I haven't been able to find any exact definitions of what they indicate. Could someone give me a quick explanation or point me somewhere that has one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And the last part:  `foo*` is often used for the underlying function of a convenience macro `foo`.  E.g., [`log` vs `log*`](http://clojure.github.io/tools.logging/#clojure.tools.logging/log)

Comment: That answers my last question. Though looking back over the code that caused me to ask this in the first place, I think it's also used for functions underlying other helper functions, not just macros.

Answer (score 5):

Conventions for functions are...conventions. There no mandatory naming but some habits whom sometime came from lisps.

- -function is used by some programmers for private functions declared by defn-. But also
- .-function for attribute access for objects from ClojureScript.
- function? are generally boolean test function (even?, list?, ...)
- function! are functions that involve side effect.
- function name embedding -> are conversion functions.
- *var* are dynamic variables.

And a lot more from programming group conventions.

Comment: Well, that answers half my question. Any clue about function* though?

Comment: I think of function! as more specifically indicating that the function modifies the state of some data structure, as opposed to, say, printing to standard output.

Answer (score 3):

"-" and "*" are just part of a valid Clojure symbol.  They do not indicate anything special per se, and the Clojure compiler will treat them just like any other symbol.

Conventionally, *'s are used to surround the name of a dynamic var.  You can make a var dynamic without the *'s, but it might cause confusion for someone dealing with your code when the value of the var unexpectedly changes out from under them due to a `binding` call somewhere up the stack.  By including the *'s, you are reminding any users of that var that it is dynamic everytime they write/read its name.

Symbols that begin with "-" are typically used in connection with Clojure's `gen-class` construct.  That is because "-" is the default prefix to append to method names when mapping a class's method to a function.  However, there are other things it could mean as well.

As Ivan points out, there are other conventions that might be worth knowing as well.  However, they're just conventions -- like camelCasing in other languages.